# How to Achieve this UI in Flutter

Tags: user-interface, flutter

all I have created a UI for my Personal Project but it's not looking as I wanted:

[image]

Can Someone guide me how to achieve this UI as attached here?
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWzhW.png)

Comment: Did you attach the right images? The two images seem to be about completely different features

Comment: Yes, Its completely different I am trying to achieve the data as shown in the second image.  the first image has from and to address and date and time for from and to. I had got a bit of achievement but not that much as in above

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? How to layout individual widgets, or how to style the widgets?

Comment: Dear @DavidL. Please have a look on this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWzhW.png this much I have achieved Now I guess only Styling part is a bit confusing for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ListTile` widget to obtain this image https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html